# Listbox Extending too far when form opened

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a bit of an interesting situation. So inside my form designer it shows that the listbox ends at a certain point. However, when I run the program and launch the form with the listbox it makes it look like it is continuing unless I drag the window down a little. This is what it looks like when it is in Visual Studio. [image]

This is what it looks like when it is running. Notice how the listbox looks like it is just going on an don? But if I drag the window down just a little it shows an end to it. I shouldn't have to drag it down every time I run it. I feel like I am missing something. What am I missing?[image]

Comment: The window is shorter when running. Is it in another monitor? You can use the Anchor property. Make it Top-Left-Bottom for the left list, and top-right-bottom for the right one.

Comment: That just now makes the list box drag down. No grey space like their should be.

Answer (score 0):

When running a WinForms or WPF application, a "Resize border" get's added which isn't visible in the designer. If you set resize to "Can Minimize" it should work as expected.

A solution for this would be to snap it to the bottom border (I don't know if it's the same as in WPF but something like `Margin="0,0,0,0"` and `Width="150"` should do the trick)

**Edit**: I just made an test project; this worked for me: [image]

Comment: Looking at the form padding it is 0,0,0,0 and for size the width is 843 and height 1200.

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is still doing the same thing. But if I remove the bottom anchor and drag the window down just a little bit it will show the grey like it shows in Visual Studios.